# How do I configure an Action to record the current timestamp or current user?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I'd like to allow users to edit an Object and want to record the time and by whom the edit was made. Is there a way to do this with an Action?

Comment: For example do you mean you want to log on a dataset all the users that triggered that action + timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Current Timestamp can be part of your logic rule. Here are the steps to configure:

1. Generate a logic rule
2. Click in to the parameter you want to store current time
   [image: Rule configuration]
3. Select Current Timestamp from the dropdown
   [image: select timestamp]

Note that this configuration only supports timestamps, not date types.

You can follow the same steps to add Current User to a string column, for example on a "last modified by" property.